# Unable to run ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0

Tags: 14.04, networking

Joining our Ubuntu farm to a windows domain and after adding the DC's IP to /etc/network/interfaces, I try to bounce the interface as I've done on other Ubuntu servers and it errors out.

```
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0
```

/etc/network# cat run/ifstate shows:

```
lo=lo
eth2=eth2
eth1=eth1
```

I looked at /run/network/ifstate and added eth0=eth0 to the end of the file.  Still cannot run the command `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`

Due to the nature of this server, I need to keep reboots to a minimum.  Does anyone have any ideas of what is causing this issue and how I can resolve it?  We have another server with the same issue.

UPDATE: Here is the eth0 portion of my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Label public
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address XXX.XXX.X95.56
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway XXX.XXX.X95.1
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
    netmask 64
    gateway fe80::def
    dns-nameservers 192.168.XXX.XXX 173.203.4.9 173.203.4.8
```

If I run `ifconfig eth0 down` the interface goes down but `ifconfig eth0 up` does not bring it back up.  Ironically a nslookup of my AD domain works at this point.  I assume it's now using the DNS entry I added to the LAN port to do this.  Rebooting the server restores eth0.

UPDATE 2:
Running `sudo ifup -v eth0`

```
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add XXX.XXX.XX5.56/255.255.255.0 broadcast XXX.XXX.X95.255    dev eth0 label eth0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

Comment: Do you mind letting us have a look at: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: Added to my question.

Comment: **did you try `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` && `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` try check the interface also if it blocked using `sudo rfkill list`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I imaged an Ubuntu machine and laid the image on several others.  I started having them come up with interfaces that weren't named eth0 and wlan0 but rather eth1 and wlan1.

Here's what happened: There is a file that ties the MAC address of each adapter to the name of each adapter (eth{n} wlan{n} etc.).  If you boot up and the OS sees that eth0 is tied to some other MAC address (in my case, from the master machine) it will create a new interface called eth1 and things start breaking inside /etc/network/interfaces.

**Solution:  Delete the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`  and reboot (sorry, OP).  The file will be recreated at boot with the proper settings for this machine.**

For those who experience this in the context of imaging like I did, think of deleting this file as sysprep.  You'll want to delete that and then capture your image before next boot of the OS.

I can't be sure that my situation is the same as yours, but if it sounds like this makes sense, it shouldn't hurt to try it.  Good luck

Comment: My `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` is completely blank.  I tried anyways.  Same result.

Comment: I think I recall seeing this file named something else once or twice in the past.  What are the contents of /etc/udev/rules.d/    ?

Comment: 70-persistent-net.rules  README